# Detect if a URL to a video contains an audio track with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I am making a program where I must check if a *video* has an *audio track*. I have put my code below. I know that my code works, but it is kind of hackish, and I would prefer to not do it this way. If you have a suggestion or answer, I would love to know what it is.

```js
var videoURL = 'https://www.example.com/video.mp4';
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = videoURL;
video.play();
video.onplaying = function() {
    var audio = Boolean(video.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount);
    console.log(audio);
    video.pause();
};
```

#### Edit:

For some reason, this question has been associated with another question that was asked more than **six years ago** about how to detect if the video element has sound. My code above shows something similar to answers in that question. *The code is a work around.* I would like to see if a *video file* has audio. It is preferable for me to do it through the  `fetch` API.

Comment: Mhm, someone downvoted a question that meets all of the Stack Overflow requirements. Also, please note that I will be giving this a bounty on November 4. In case if you haven't noticed or don't understand this question, I will explain in further detail: **How can one detect if a video file has an audio track?** I am asking for a non-hackish answer. I really appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: If the answers there are still "too `hackish`" for your standards, feel free to open a bounty there. Having multiple times the same question with answers spreading all around doesn't help the community.

Comment: @Kaiido, I was planning on opening a bounty, but my question was closed. I would appreciate a reopen vote :)

Comment: And you won't get mine no. How the fact the question is 6 years old matters? In no way. Both are still asking for the same thing. If someone in the future wants to solve the same problem they'll have to go through many questions with many similar answers that won't be able to compete fairly, breaking our whole model of votes. So as I said, go there and  open a bounty on that question.